# Ruby: Process.wait is throwing `Invalid Argument` exception on long operations of +300 seconds

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0

I have the following ruby script which kicks off 12 processes which smoke test my application.  Some of these can be long running of up to 8 minutes.

```
pids = []

pids = uris.map do |uri|
    print_start(uri)
    command = get_http_tests_command("Smoke")
    update_http_tests_config( uri )
    pid = Process.spawn command
    Process.detach pid
    pid
end

print( "smoke tests in progress => #{pids} => #{uris}" )

statuses = pids.map do |pid| 
    puts "waiting for #{pid}"
    Process.wait( pid )
    $?
end

print("smoke tests finished")
```

When the process finishes regardless of success I intermittently get an error on the `Process.wait( pid )` line.  The error is as follows

```
#<Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument>

>> SmokeTest.rb:169:in "wait"
>> SmokeTest.rb:169:in "block in run_single"
>> SmokeTest.rb:167:in "map"
>> SmokeTest.rb:167:in "run_single"
```

I'm not sure what's going on here, any help would be much appreciated.  It seems to fail intermittently about 1 in 3 times under 300 seconds.  It always fails if it goes over 300 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that this exception is thrown if you try to `wait` on a process which is already dead...

If that is the problem I could suggest using threads to wait for all processes concurrently:

```
statuses = []

threads = pids.map do |pid| 
  Thread.new do
    puts "waiting for #{pid}"
    _, status = Process.wait2( pid )
    puts "#{pid} ended with status #{status}"
    statuses << status
  end
end

threads.each(&:join)
print("smoke tests finished")
```

Comment: Being a bit thick - what's the purpose of this `threads.each(&:join)` ?

Comment: Is the `&` the subject of the each?  I guess this is probably for blocking?

Comment: This is shorthand for 'threads.each { |x| x.join }' which waits for all threads to complete